# What would a 300% decrease in something actually mean?

Tags: terminology, percentages

I was looking at a site search product and one of the testimonials was

`300% drop in "no results" searches`

What would this manifest as ?

All I can come up with is -2 "no results searches" for every one that did exist but that doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Or is this likely just a misuse of percentages to make the product look good ?

Comment: Could be what you'd normally call a 75% reduction, but I'd expect there's no sense to this usage.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a misuse of percentages. It could be unknowingly, or deliberately, as you just said.

> A quantity can not decrease by more than 100% of itself.

By the way, you could have Googled it before asking on SE. Here's the first Google Search result that came up for me: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110122151445AApNB9I

Comment: i did try googling it, that was not one of the results for me

Comment: @Cob50mn What did you type in google ?